# creating a struct for file/directory tree

Tags: c, shell, file-io

how would one go about creating a struct for a file/directory tree. The c program gets a txt file input with shell scripts of the paths of each txt file. for example

```
a\a1.txt
a\m\m1.txt
```

how would you create a struct for this?

Comment: Using the `struct` keyword, in first place.

Comment: A struct is a way of organizing data. What will your program do with the data it reads from the input file?

Comment: the user runs the C program and inputs the name of a text file, it should search for 
the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe

for an simple one dimensional string of strings

```
struct MyPath {
    char *element;  // Pointer to the string of one part.
    MyPath *next;   // Pointer to the next part - NULL if none.
}
```

for the full binary tree representation

```
struct Node {
   char *element; // Pointer to the string - node.
   Node *left;    // Pointer to the left subtree.
   Node *right;   // Pointer to the right subtree.
}
```